# How to get difference of elements of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to calculate difference of array elements(not difference of arrays) in PHP. I have used `array_diff()` but it gives only difference of 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT - Understood what OP was requesting**

unfortunately, there is no native PHP function to handle an opposite to array_sum()

Here's a function you could use though

```
function array_sub($arry) {
    return eval("return (" . implode("-",$arry) . ");");
}

$a=array("a"=>52,"b"=>13,"c"=>10);
echo array_sub($a); //Result == 29
```

Comment: Thanks josh for your support. But my problem is not solved yet. Here is my array $a=array("a"=>52,"b"=>13,"c"=>10);
echo array_sum($a) when i am using array_sum() i got the out put as '75'. In this way i need to get the difference of elemnts arrays.

Comment: Providing an example and what you are expecting to have as the result will allow us to help find a solution.

Comment: Thanks josh for your support. But my problem is not solved yet. Here is my array $a=array("a"=>52,"b"=>13,"c"=>10);
echo array_sum($a) when i am using array_sum() i got the out put as '75'. In this way i need to get the difference of elemnts arrays.

Comment: Ah, i see you are looking for the mathematical differences, i'll post another answer

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your need